# AttributeError: 'search' object has no attribute 'status_code' in django project

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I'm testing a django project using the test sever when it gives me the following exception

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 280, in run
>      self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 674, in >**call**
>      return self.application(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in **call**
>      response = middleware_method(request, response)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/middleware/common.py", line 84, in >process_response
>      if response.status_code == 404:
>
> AttributeError: 'search' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Just from reading this traceback, I don't think the problem is in my code, but I'm not sure. Could someone look through my code and help me solve this problem? my code is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/levicc00123/MusicGrep) and any other comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: same file `search` it will return what? for sure not a HttpResponse instance - and this is exactly source of your problem

Comment: then, use `.gitignore` read pep8 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code, but the one that's causing the actual error you quote is that you don't instantiate your FormWizard subclass in your urlconf.

As [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#hooking-the-wizard-into-a-urlconf) shows, you need to actually call the `search` class in urls.py to instantiate it, so you pass an instance rather than a class.

```
(r'^MusicGrep/$', 'MusicGrep.musicgrep.forms.search()'),
```

It might help if you followed the PEP8 guidelines on naming - if your class was called `Search` with a capital S, it would be more obvious that it was actually a class and not a function.

Comment: If you have the time, could you please send me an email with a list of problems you've noticed? I'd like to use this for a startup I'm working on and I'd like to have as much done as possible before I present to potential investors. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

`MusicGrep/musicgrep/views.py` is not returning a HttpResponse instance